# pip install theano on virtualenv python unicode related error

Tags: python, unicode, virtualenv

Recently, I tried to install theano on virtualenv without sudo permission. I met a lot of problems and I solved most of them with the help of SO. However, I have no idea how to solve the last one. But I think it's important to put my entire procedure here since it's not that many. I really wish someone can tell me where goes wrong.

First I download a python-2.7.3.tar.gz file, extract it and try to install python with

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME --enable-shared && make && make install
```

but there will be a problem when I try to create a virtual machine:

```
undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_Replace
```

So, with the help of this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584198/undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs2-decode-whilst-trying-to-install-psycopg2) post, I remove all the files in lib/, bin/ and include/ and tried the following command:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME --enable-shared --enable-unicode=ucs4 && make && make install
```

Then I tried to create a virtual machine with this command:

```
python virtualenv-1.10/virtualenv.py -p /afs/cs.cmu.edu/usr/haohanw/bin/python --no-site-packages --distribute test
```

And virtual machine works.
(P.S. if I use Python-2.7.8 or Python-2.7.7, there will be an error: `undefined symbol: _PyLong_AsInt` here.)

Then, I activate the virtual machine with `source test/bin/activate`,
and install numpy first with `pip install numpy`,
then according to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496547/python-scipy-needs-blas) post, I changed some configurations.
According to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555761/pip-install-pandas-gives-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0) post, I run `pip install --upgrade pip`

Now with pip version 1.5.6 and python version 2.7.3, I run `pip install scipy` and unfortunately got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/afs/cs.cmu.edu/user/haohanw/private/deeplearning/test/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/afs/cs.cmu.edu/user/haohanw/private/deeplearning/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
return command.main(cmd_args)
File "/afs/cs.cmu.edu/user/haohanw/private/deeplearning/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have been working on it for four days, can someone help me with it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you print the whole stack trace error because one line of error statement is not sometimes enough for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks, @NonymousNT I added the whole stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. 
When I create the virtualenv, I should use the python I just compiled, rather than the one that is built in the system. I think they are different because I compiled python with `--enable-unicode=ucs4`

Comment: Also found the fact that `sudo` can properly avoid this problem, but no idea way