# Unable to import python module lxml on MAC

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pip, lxml

Unable to import lxml from terminal on MAC. Getting this below error

**ERROR:**

```
python
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 12:01:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyUnicodeUCS4_AsASCIIString
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

>>> 

'import lxml' works fine
```

**Python path**

```
which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

**when i look for lxml installation, everything looks fine**

```
pip install lxml
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

pip2 install lxml
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

What am i missing here ? what could be wrong ? can you please help me.

**SOLUTION:**
solved it by uninstalling `lxml` and re-installed by `pip install lxml --no-binary :all:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2\_Decode whilst trying to install psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584198/undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs2-decode-whilst-trying-to-install-psycopg2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install Lxml on Mac os x 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548011/cannot-install-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-9)

Answer (score 0):

You have python compiled with UCS4 (4-bytes unicode) and lxml with UCS2. I.e., the extension and python are incompatible. Change one of them — that is, recompile python with `--enable-unicode=ucs2` or recompile lxml with UCS4.

Comment: solved it by uninstalling lxml and re-installed by pip install lxml --no-binary :all: , updated my answer above.